# How to update "/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/" libraries on ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, updates, libraries

A Ubuntu 12.04 LTS platform is been used to develop embedded Linux software for ARM cortex-A8 hardware platform (beaglebone black).

To communicate on the I2C bus on target device, it is recommended to use i2c_smbus_ functions to communicate on the I2C bus. When **i2c_smbus** functions such as **i2c_smbus_read_word_data** are referenced in software for the target ARM Cortex-A8 processor errors such as ‘i2c_smbus_read_word_data’ was not declared in this scope are generated at compile.

It appears that the following header files indicate that they are dated.

- /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/linux/i2c.h
- /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/linux/i2c-dev.h

Also in that following reference [i2c.h](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/i2c.h#L80) file has all the i2c_smbus defined.

How can all arm-linux-gnueabi libraries be updated?

**Research references**

- [Using I2C from userspace in Linux](https://xgoat.com/wp/2007/11/11/using-i2c-from-userspace-in-linux/)
- [I2C Communication from Linux Userspace – Part II](http://www.ctrlinux.com/blog/?p=38)
- [I2C dev interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface)

Answer (score 0):

Install **i2c_tools** and **libi2c-dev** packages